# Multiplicar dos campos situados en tablas diferentes en phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]no consigo averiguar como conseguir la multiplicación de dos campos (PRECIO y CANTIDAD) en php situados en dos tablas distintas( CESTA, LIBRO) de una base de datos llamada librería en phpmyadmin.

He hecho la siguiente consulta pero no me va

```
 SELECT SUM(cantidad*precio) total 
FROM CESTA, LIBRO
```

;

Comment: Podrias agregar la definición de las dos tablas y como se relacionan entre sí?

Comment: No tienen relación porque tampoco creo que las necesite. He dejado la foto

Comment: En tu tabla libros no hay la columna precio

Comment: creo que aparte tu query seria algo como `SELECT SUM (cesta.cantidad*libros.precio) total 
FROM cesta, libros;`

Comment: y para conseguir que me imprima esa multiplicación?   He probado esto pero no consigo que me muestre el resultado.                                   $query = " SELECT SUM (cesta.cantidad*libros.precio) total FROM cesta, libros";
  $resultado1 = mysqli_query( $enlaceBD, $query);

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionó Jose M Herrera V, en ninguna tabla está el precio.
pero suponiendo que el precio está en **libros** y de tipo int
la consulta sería de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT 
(CE.cantidad*LI.precio) AS total_conjunto 
FROM cesta AS CE
INNER JOIN libros AS LI
ON CE.id_libro = LI.id;
```

Comment: Sería mejor no suponer y responder sólo con la información exacta de pregunta